# Gigabit Ethernet switch from 1Gbps to 100Mbps back and forth

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

Alright, you're my last chance on resolving this problem that I have been trying to fix for a couple of months so far.

**Problem**

My gigabit Ethernet speed switches from 1Gbps to 100Mbps frequently. This issue occurs usually, and there is no time pattern in switching between speeds. It switches by itself just like that. Sometimes, it sticks at 1Gbps for days and then switches to 100Mbps, and sometimes it just switches in a matter of hours. Same thing happens conversely.

**More details**

I just moved from United State to another country, so I am a 3 months of experience in this country. I also use the same laptop, and I hadn't have any problem in using a gigabit connection.

I am connected to internet through fiber optics with a maximum speed of 200Mbps. The network diagram is as following :

```
Cable Box → Router → PC
```

- **Router:** [Huawei HG8245](http://www1.huawei.com/en/products/fixed-access/fttx/ont/hg8245/index.htm)
- **Laptop:** [GT70 2QD DOMINATOR](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GT70-2QD-Dominator.html#hero-specification)
- **Network adapter:** [Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller](http://www.killernetworking.com/products/e2200)
- **Cable Box to Router:** SC Fiber Optic Cable
- **Router to PC:** CAT 6 (UTP) / 240MHz / (20m/ 65ft Long)

The router is provided from the ISP, which they disabled most of the features(options) that can the user change (as a protection of misuse) leaving the common features editable (WAN, LAN, Wireless..etc). So, not all options in the router can be edited. I called them as I want to request a replacement to a new modem (not a router), so I can buy a router and connect it to the modem, like what I used to do when I was in U.S , but they told me they only provide routers. (AND NO I haven't changed it yet, still waiting for the ISP to accept my request of a replacement). The router has 4 GE ports and they're divided by 2 categories. LAN 1 & 2 are for general purposes (for computers and other devices), and LAN 3 & 4 are for TV-Box service. My cat 6 cable is connected to LAN 1, and there is a cat 5 cable on LAN2 for my brother's computer in a different room.

**What I have tried so far**

- Tried 4 different CAT 6 cables from different manufactures. **(No Luck)**.
- Tried to force the connection speed using "Speed & Duplex" parameters on my laptop, but there is no 1Gbps option in the drop-down list (no clue why), so left it at (Auto Negotiation).
- Tried to search online for a solution, read, applied. (No Luck)
- Tried to update drivers, uninstalled, reinstalled them (As I have found some complaints on my current E2200 network adapter). (No Luck)
- Tried to test the cables on different computers, and they work like a charm, but since I couldn't hold these computer and put them on test for a couple of days, I didn't consider it as a full test.
- Tried to connect two computers via Ethernet, with the same cable, and it works with 1Gbps of speed perfectly.

**What's Next**
I am thinking that this issue is from the router, While I've tried to change settings, but as I mentioned is protected from the ISP, so I am waiting for the ISP to send a replacement, which will take months to be replaced. So, I am trying to figure out the problem, because it bugs me, and I need to know how to fix it. As most of the online solutions didn't work.

**Comments Answers:**

- Power Management is on High Performance, and modified the advanced settings to a %100 of working performance with all hardware.
- Power Savings is disabled in all hardware including the network adapter.
- Windows NIC connector tested with different computer, and it seems in good condition, has no reflects nor bad reports. Plus, it was working great with Linksys EA6900 AC1900 for over an year with no issues with a gigabit connection.
- Flow Control Option was set to Rx & Tx Enabled, then turned off (Disabled).
- Maximum length of using 1Gbps connection was 3 days in a row, then the connection reconnected by itself with a 100Mbps speed.
- The router LAN lease time is set by default to 3 hours.
- Disconnected LAN 2, and kept only LAN 1 connected. (No Change).
- Switch Killer E2200 NIC into Qualcomm Atheros AR8161. (No Change)
- Turned back my Killer's E2200 and updated the drivers from the Killer's website. (No Change)

I tried to be as much detailed as possible.

**Update 7/20/2016**

Today, I was reviewing my SSD settings to optimize its performance. So, I have made these changes :

- Disabled Hibernation Mode
- Disabled Virtual Memory (As I have 32GB of physical memory)
- Disabled Prefetch / Superfetch
- Enabled Over Provisioning (OP) for my SSD.
- Disabled Ethernet, Wireless, Bluetooth, Adhoc.
- Used CCleaner to clean up the temporary files.
- Next, Restarted my computer, and then re-enabled Ethernet, WiFi, Bluetooth, and Adhoc.

When I enabled Ethernet, it just connected with a 1 Gbps. I was surprised because for the last 19 days my Ethernet speed was stuck at 100 Mbps, and this was the longest time I have experienced in 100 Mbps. I do not know if this solved the problem or not, so I will be monitoring this problem this week and see what happens.

**Update 7/26/2016**

It has been almost 6 days, and I have not experienced any issue with my connection speed. I am still wondering what was the cause of this issue, but it seems everything is working flawlessly after I optimized my SSD performance settings.

I think I can say this case is closed. Big thanks for those who tried to think through this issue and bring a solution.

Comment: Is there any performance reduction settings in your BIOS/UEFI firmware like there is for the CPU performance on many computers (especially laptops to reduce battery consumption)...? There may also be some power settings for the device in `Device Manager` that mentions about reducing link speed when on battery or standby

Comment: Test the NIC connector for the device you have problems with. It may have a faulty connector wire.

Comment: @BigChris, there are some reduction settings in BIOS for CPU and USB. There is nothing related to LAN except two options one for Network Stack and the other one is for Network boot, which I don't use. And for power savings, it's disabled, in fact, my settings is modified to  Higher Performance with %100 of performance on all hardware, and always connected to AC, I rarely run the laptop on battery.

Comment: @Overmind, I've already test it, and it seems in a good condition, there is no conflicts in Windows device manager logs, plus it worked with the full speed when I connected to another computer.

Comment: You need to go to `Device Manager` on your laptop to get the advanced network card settings: This image should help http://kb.parallels.com/Attachments/kcs-32201/WoL_Windows.png. Your adapter will be different and the screens may have some extra options but there may be a "reduce link speed" options for the manufacturer's tab of options. http://h30434.www3.hp.com/psg/attachments/psg/Business-PC-Workstation-POS/4352/1/unchek.JPG (this is intel but it shows the option)

Comment: @BigChris, the Power Management options is disabled (I've already un-ticked those options that you provided in the figures). I always make that steps on my devices as I don't use power savings nor letting the devices controls the power management. So, my settings is set to full performance in all hardware.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your network adapter screen with the tabs

Comment: @BigChris, check it out : https://s32.postimg.org/fx2quaa1x/devicemanager.png

Comment: What's under the "Advanced" tab? :) P.s. thank you for your quick responses!

Comment: @BigChris, here is the advanced tab : https://s31.postimg.org/vhg4jlypn/advancedtab.png

Comment: Try disabling "Flow control"

Comment: @BigChris, Flow control is now disabled, but I have to wait for a couple of days to see if it changes anything or the problem will come back again, because a couple of hours ago, the speed switched to 1Gbps and I don't know when it's going to switch again to 100Mbps. So, I need more days to monitor it and see the changes.

Comment: Is there a possibility of interference from thinks like electrical transformers or power lines ?

Comment: @Overmind, I don't think so, since the electricity in my home is stable, plus  I am using a power stabilizer to connect my laptop and monitor on it.

Comment: @BigChris, Sadly, disabling Flow Control option didn't solve it, the Ethernet just switched into 100Mbps today.

Comment: You may also eventually try this https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/guide-turn-your-killer-e2200-nic-into-qualcomm-atheros-ar8161.198899/

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal, I have tried this before, and it didn't solve it, I also updated the drivers from Killer site, and didn't solve it as well.

Comment: Have you checked the cabling? A flaky cable could cause this problem. When using 100BASE-TX (100 Mbps), ethernet only needs two pairs (1-2 and 3-6), but 1000BASE-T (1Gbps) requires all four pairs (1-2, 3-6, 4-5, and 7-8). When ethernet autonegotiates (a requirement for 1000BASE-T), and all four pairs don't work correctly, it will fall back to 100BASE-TX.

Comment: @RonMaupin Actually I did, and this problem was resolved. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the conclusion of the post above:

If you have the same issue, then follow these steps :

- Make sure your network adapter supports an 1 Gbps connection or higher. (e.g Gigabit Ethernet Controller 10/100/1000)
- Make sure your router has Gigabit LAN ports (GE).
- Make sure your ethernet cable is CAT5e, CAT6 or higher.

**On Windows Side:**

- Make sure that `Speed & Duplex` parameter is set to Auto Negotiation. (You can set it to 1000 Mbps/ 1 Gbps manually).
- Set the Power Management to High Performance and modified the advanced settings to a %100 of working performance with all hardware.
- Disable `Power Savings` on the network adapter.
- Disable `Hibernation Mode`
- Disable `Prefetch / Superfetch`
- **(FOR SSD) Enable `Over Provisioning (OP)` with %10 of SSD capacity.**

**Update 8/1/2016**

I figured it out, Enabling the `Over Provisioning (OP)` for the SSD will fix the issue. As I tried to delete it, when I did, the network speed immediately switched back to 100Mbps, and when I set the OP again, the network speed went back to 1Gbps.

Don't forgot to disable the Ethernet and turn off your router, then restart your computer and then power on your router again and re-enable your ethernet.

For more details on what I have experienced, read the full post above.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue: the NIC synced on 100M, physical cable disconnect-reconnect solved the problem for few hours.

Since my SSD is plain without SSD management tool for windows I didn't have the ability to configure Over Provisioning.

After shrinking the data partition on my SSD and reserving 10% of the unpartitioned disk for SSD housekeeping, the NIC stayed sync on 1G forever.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem since the last 2 weeks its just suddenly happened i tried a lot of thing my internet adapter settings are the same as in the Original Question thread, anyways what I was curious about is how does my speed being 1gbit and dropping to 100M has anything to do with my ssd though and since I only have a M.2 NVME ssd(OP-sys on this) and a HDD in the PC should i only over provision the ssd and thats it?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1129650)